# Change from RHEL 7.7 to RHCOS

Tags: openshift, redhat, rhel7, coreos

I would like to get started with OpenShift 4.7 (for the first time) and therefore need to update my OS from RHEL 7.7 to RHCOS.

I tried to search for some help but it is still not clear to me what to do / is the fastest way to make this update.

Could anyone provide me some guidance / help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version(s) of OpenShift were you using before.  If it was 3.x then the process was to install RHEL and then install OpenShift on top of it.  With 4.x, the installer itself lays down RHCOS on the underlying node.

See: https://cloud.redhat.com/openshift/install

If you want to test the waters to start, look at CRC (single node, OpenShift, non production, developer or testing only, that runs in a VM on your desktop) - https://cloud.redhat.com/openshift/create/local

--> you don't update your OS from RHEL to RHCOS.  You just (let the OpenShift installer) install RHCOS.